# C removing array elem, program stops

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, crash

Ok so I'm trying to make a database-like easy C program which means adding elements in an array. A static array made out of structs:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char active[20];
    int quantity;
} Medicine;
```

These next 2 are in another module

```
typedef Medicine ElemType;

typedef struct {
    int len;
    ElemType medList[30];
} StaticList;
```

Ok, everything fine until I tried to make a function to remove an element from this static array based a name. Like the used gives me a name, and I delete the element whose name matches to the one given.

```
void removeElem(StaticList *l, char* value) {
    int k;
    k = l->len;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        Medicine m = get(l, i);
        if (strcmp(m.name, value)==0) {
            int j = i;
            for (j = i; j<k-1; j++) {
                l[j] = l[j+1];---changed to ->> l->medList[j] = l->medList[j+1];
            }
            (*l).len--;
            break;
        }
        i++;
        if (i == k-1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem? My program has the following functionalities:
-Add elem
-List all the elems
-Remove elem

If I add 1 elem, then I delete it... my list should be empty right? Well mine gets filled up. When I try to add another element, my program crashes and in order to find out what happened and how long my list is... I puta print after emptying the list and it says "4406168 Elems added".
So basically I start from 0, add 1 elem, try to remove it and my array gets filled with  4406168 more? What's happening?

If further info is requires, I'll provide anything. Thank you.

Comment: Is the length of your list equal to 1 when you enter `removeElem()`? If so, you need to have a proper think about what will happen when you reach the instructions `i++; if (i == k-1) { ... }`. Also, `(*l).len--` is just plain weird. Use `l->len--` instead.

Comment: In C,I thought arrays start from 0. Like... If I have 1 elem, the length is 1 but the position is 0. So k=1 ( length), i = 0 (position) when I have 1 element. I tried changing to l->len-- and it still crashed for my tests... :/ It fills my array and I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, but `i` isn't zero. Not after you've incremented it.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
    int len;
    int a[10];
} List;

void removeElem(List& list, const int val)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < list.len){

        if(list.a[i] == val){ // if match
            // copy values forward
            for(int j=i+1;j<list.len;++j){
                list.a[j-1] = list.a[j];
            }
            --list.len;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```